# Flutter how to get maximum possible lines in a Text widget with given size?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-android

I have to know how many lines are fitting in a Text with given size and TextStyle.
I played around with `TextPainter` but this does only provide information if the max lines are exceeded but not what's the last char index of the string that fits into it.

**Usecase:**
I have to split a string into multiple Text widgets which have a fixed size ands text style.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can use TextSpan for different styles for your text.
Here is an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextSpanExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: "TextSpan number 1",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 14,
                ),
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: "TextSpan number 2",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                ),
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: "TextSpan number 3",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
            ]
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Maybe I phrased it wrong,
I tried to re-phrase it over at Reddit, please see: https://www.reddit.com/r/flutterhelp/comments/mrc64j/how_to_get_maximum_possible_lines_in_a_text/